# Lubuntu 17.10 doesn't see wifi device

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu

I've just installed lubuntu 17.10, updated all packages and enabled additional drivers. No luck with wifi devices. "system profiler and benchmark"->network->interfaces does not show and wifi devices, only local and ethernet.

`lsusb` shows this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci | grep -i wireless` shows nothing

`rfkill list all` shows only bluetooth device

notebook HP 15-bs635ur

please help :3

Comment: Your wifi isn't supported, check results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` and the results will likely show Realtek Device [10ec:d723]

Comment: Thanks for answering, you are correct https://i.imgur.com/TEhONzV.png 

Is there a solution or I will not be able to use wifi on this notebook on any linux system?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, found the answer already. It'll be supported in a few months. So back to windows I guess.

Comment: Or you could buy a cheap fully supported USB wifi in the meantime.